# Python - Adding items to the front of dict list

Tags: python

```
Basket = {'John': [3, 12, 1], 'Billy': [2, 5, 3], 'Ben': [3, 3, 8]}
```

This is my dict list. How do I add new items at the front showed in the picture? Should I use `append` or `insert`?

[image: 1]

Comment: Can you explain the problem little bit more clearer?

Comment: do you want to add information for total fruits, total pear + total apple?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `insert`. `append` pushes it to the back. This is how you would use `insert` to insert in the total front of the list:

```
Basket = {'John': [3, 12, 1], 'Billy': [2, 5, 3], 'Ben': [3, 3, 8]}
Basket["John"].insert(0, 6)
```

Comment: this is a list not a dictionary

Comment: @seralouk -- Yes, I was showing I general example. I updated it.

Answer (score 0):

### The `update` method works fine.

Example:

```
Basket = {'John': [3, 12, 1], 'Billy': [2, 5, 3], 'Ben': [3, 3, 8]}

d = {'John': [16, 4, 3, 12, 1]}
Basket.update(d)

Basket
{'John': [16, 4, 3, 12, 1], 'Billy': [2, 5, 3], 'Ben': [3, 3, 8]}
```

Comment: Why is it nested in another list? Also, that’s the end, not the front.

Comment: This appends to the back, not front.

Comment: check again my answer